# Get specific content from an external url - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get the direct download link from Google Drive, so I want to get specific content from external url.

Example: visit *x* link and get the url from this div or from this class! I think that this is possible, but I don't know how to do it.

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument;
 libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
 $dom->loadHTMLFile('https://drive.google.com/uc?id=12ejMrVziFpjcEpG9A2Ks4yoNDJ9qz0B5&export=download');
 $DOMxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
 $DivContent = $DOMxpath->query("//div[@id='uc-download-link']");
 $bigDiv = $DivContent;
 $link = $bigDiv->find('a');
 echo $link->href . '<br>';
```

Is that possible with <kbd>PHP</kbd> or <kbd>JavaScript</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it can be done easily with php's `file_get_contents`, `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`.

The following example gets the `HREF` value from the 'Stack Overflow' logo's `<a>` tag, which has the class `-logo js-gps-track`:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// find the element whose href value you want by XPath
$nodes = $xpath->query('//*[@class="-logo js-gps-track"]');

foreach($nodes as $href) {
    // print out the href value
    echo $href->getAttribute( 'href' ); 
}
```

Obviously you'd just need to amend the URL and the XPath for your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks for your help, so in my case, the url is this `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=12ejMrVziFpjcEpG9A2Ks4yoNDJ9qz0B5&export=download` and the class name is `jfk-button-action` and after this class, is the download url that what i want to get, after I put your code, I tried to get the link  `<?php echo $href;?>` but is not working!

Comment: If you do a `file_get_contents` on that URL, you'll see it only retrieves the file data.  It's not an HTML URL

Comment: so how i can get, the download link can you show full code, thanks

Comment: now I have test to get the Stack Overflow logo, but is not working, that get the Stack Overflow Url https://stackoverflow.com not the logo url!

Comment: The URL you provided *is* the direct download link.  I can't tell you what the URL is that would contain that link - you'd have to find that page and go from there.  The example I pasted in for stackexchange works - the URL on the logo *is* 'http://www.stackexchange.com'

Comment: Thanks for your help, your code is working perfect, it was my mistake. but  your code is working perfect. Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

Would it be fair to say that you're trying to scrape links from an external page?  If so, there's very popular JS package called Cheerio, which allows you to access elements the same way as jQuery.  It runs on Node https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio but it seems to be available via CDN at https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/cheerio

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i need some code ful code i can't do that by my self, thanks again

Answer (score -2):

Definitely possible with both PHP & JavaScript. Thing is, how you want to approach it. To get the download link from drive by parsing DOM, I will use these packages:

PHP : simple_html_dom package

NODE JS : cheerio

PYTHON : simple request library with bs4

You can just filter with find() to locate download link text section and grab it finally with plaintext() method of simple_html_dom

**Example**

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('gdriveurl');

$target = $html->find('a'):

echo $target->href
*(This is the download link )*

Another easiest solution is xpath

Comment: please, can you show me a code? to do this function? thanks

Comment: Added in answer.

Comment: somthing still missing, ca you show full code thanks again

Comment: You will have to download that library from SourceForge and replace ^gdriveurl with your Google drive url. Let me know if any further issue